# How to print a space between each letter of a word in a list on a new line?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

### What I want

```
sentence = ["This","is","a","short","sentence"]

# Desired Output

T h i s
i s
a
s h o r t
s e n t e n c e
>>>
```

### What I tried

```
sentence = [row.replace(""," ") for row in sentence]

for item in sentence:
    print(item)
```

The problem with this is that it prints a space at the beginning and end of every line but I only want a space between each letter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `str.join()`

```
sentence = ["This","is","a","short","sentence"]

for w in sentence:
    print(' '.join(w))
```

Comment: Thanks, `str.join()` seems convenient in this case

Answer (score 5):

You could use the facts that a string is a sequence, a sequence can be split into its items with the splat `*` operator, and and the `print` function prints items by default separated by spaces. Those three facts can be combined into one short line, `print(*word)`, if `word` is a string. So you can use

```
sentence = ["This","is","a","short","sentence"]

for word in sentence:
    print(*word)
```

This gives the printout

```
T h i s
i s
a
s h o r t
s e n t e n c e
```

Comment: I love this alternative, but how does it compare to the typical, also correct, `str.join` answer in terms of performance? Are they the same under the hood?

Comment: Using `%timeit` in iPython, SpghttCd's code used 1.33 ms, while mine used 5.18 ms. So my code is slightly shorter in code but significantly longer in execution. I suspect that Python uses time to figure how to print each item in my code, while in SpghttCd's code only one item is printed. That item takes longer to prepare but is faster to print--apparently, much faster. "Under the hood," the setup to print each item must be large, similar to how Python's handling of lists-of-lists is slower than numpy's arrays.